# Index subfolder and external sites with joomla search

Tags: search, joomla, indexing, joomla2.5

In one of the subfolders of my joomla-site, I have a piwigo pfoto-galerie plus there is a onlineshop on a subdomain. 
I would like to index these two pages with the joomla-search, so that a search on the main site also shows pages from the galerie and the shop. 
I couldn't find a joomla-plugin for that. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no one-suits all solution, sometimes you need to use your own imagination and write such plugin. See 
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin

Comment: For indexing you would be using smart search rather than search http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Smart_Search_plug-in